# How to fix the size of the <html:select> combo box (contents may be larger but the combo size should be fixed)

Tags: html, struct

How to fix the size of the  combo box (contents may be larger but the combo size should be fixed).Now my combo size is changed based on the items in the combo.

I'm trying to get something similar to the yahoo sign up page security Question combo:
https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.src=fpctx&.intl=in&.done=http://in.yahoo.com/

my code:

 Text which decides the size of the combo

Comment: The combo on that page has the text determining the width of the box so I don't understand what your trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

```
<select style="width: 100px">
  <option>Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery lllllllllllllloooong option</option>
</select>
```

or even better

```
<style>
.fixed-size  {
  width: 100px;
}
</style>

<select class="fixed-size">
  <option>Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery lllllllllllllloooong option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the css style to "width:100px" or whatever width you want the combo box to be.